# open office sort - month and year

Tags: openoffice-calc

I just want to sort this based on Month and year combination (that is, based on column A) ascending. How to do this in OpenOffice Calc? The sort option on month is not working because I guess the year is also appended.

Here are some data starting from A1:

```
Month                    Total
September 2011           27825
September 2010           35801
October 2011             108485
October 2010             22223
November 2011            139222
May 2012                 39319
May 2011                 38226
May 2010                 9671
```

Comment: More appropriate for [SuperUser](http://superuser.com)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are different solutions:

- You could transform the values of column A as dates so OpenOffice / LibreOffice can sort them accordingly (see **Solution 1** below);
- You could split the text values into two columns (month and year separately) and sort first for year, then for month (see **Solution 2** below).

### Solution 1

1. Select the cells holding the month/year values;
2. Select Menu `Format` -> `Cells...` -> `Numbers`;
3. Select `Date` from left list;
4. Enter the following format code in the `Format Code` field: `MMMM YYYY`
   [image: format]
5. Hit `OK`
6. With the cells still selected, select Menu `Edit` -> `Find & Replace...` or hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
7. In field `Search for`, enter a single dot, and in field `Replace with` an ampersand (`&`) ; hit <kbd>More Options</kbd>, tick `Regular Expression`. Select <kbd>Replace all</kbd>:

   [image: search]
8. Select cell A1, apply sorting using Menu `Data` -> `Sort` by column A ("month").

As result, OpenOffice / LibreOffice transforms the values of column A into dates (for example, 01/09/2011 instead of September 2011). The displayed cell content will stay "September 2011" because of the custom cell format using the code `MMMM YYYY`. When sorting, OpenOffice / LibreOffice recognizes the dates and sorts by month/date.

### Solution 2

1. Insert a new column next to col A for the year values: select column B, select Menu `Insert` -> `Columns`;
2. Select column A, select Menu `Data` -> `Text to Columns...`
3. In the following dialogue, select `Space` as delimiter, then hit <kbd>OK</kbd>;
4. Add `Year` as header in cell B1;
5. Select cell A1, select Menu `Data` -> `Sort`; select first year, then month; **don't** hit <kbd>OK</kbd> yet (otherwise the months would get sorted alphabetically), but select `Options` -> `Custom sort order`; select the months sort order. Now, hit <kbd>OK</kbd>.